# How to auto restart a service after crash on solaris 11?

Tags: service, solaris

On linux, in systemctl services by setting 'restart=always' restarts any service automatically in case it crashes, how can we do the same in svcs service on solaris?
I just found option 'restart_on' for dependencies. This does not serve my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default mode in Solaris SMF - you get it by not marking a service as transient, periodic, scheduled, etc.  The SMF documentation calls this "Contract or daemon service" in the [SMF Service Models documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60998/dzhid.html#SVSVFsvcmodels).